# Angular App inside asp.net core 2 requires node.js?

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I have an existing Asp.Net Core 2 MVC app and want to add an angular front end view that gets data from the MVC Web API. Will this require Node.js? (Also if anyone has any tips on tutorials on how to integrate angular into an existing project it would be appreciated).

Comment: Are you referring to [tag:Angular] (2.x+) or [tag:angularjs] (1.x) here?  Your question refers to Angular but uses the angularjs tag.  These are entirely different frameworks.  One of them ***optionally*** uses a package manager, which would involve node.js;  the other is completely independent.

Comment: @Claies Thanks for the warning. I need it to be Angular2 !

Comment: ok, and are you using TypeScript to write your angular code?

Comment: That is the plan, even if it has not happened yet.

Comment: well then that will **absolutely** require Node.js, since it's a critical piece of the workflow of compiling the TypeScript into JavaScript.

Comment: @Claies I understand. Thats good to know!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visual Studio 2017 Community (or better) provides templates for ASP.NET Core WebAPI and Angular combined.

You will need node.js for package managing. Visual Studio has a version included.

I would suggest you to completely seperate both. Use the [angular-cli](https://cli.angular.io/) for the front-end. Helps you doing all the infrastructure stuff.

Comment: I have seen the template. I cant integrate it into an existing project. Ive tried the template and ideed it needs node.js. However i have read that angular doesnt need node.js to just act as the frontend. So im trying to see if i can get away without having to introduce unnescesary complexity into the existing project.

Comment: Yes, as I said, it is not using node.js as webserver to host the angular application it is using it as webserver for packaging managing (node package manager - npm)